# A complicated limit involving floor function

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x\lfloor1/x\rfloor \rfloor $ . Find $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } f(x)  $ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{-} } f(x)$ . I think $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } f(x)$ doesn't exist but I have no idea about $\lim_{x \to 0^{-} } f(x)$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $1/x$ is an integer then $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor=1$. If $1/x$ is not an integer, and $x>0$, then $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor<1$. So the right-hand limit doesn't exist.

If $x<0$ and $1/x$ isn't an integer then $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor>1$. However, $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor<x(1/x-1)=1-x$, so provided $x>-1$ we have $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor<2$.

Comment: Can you explain about the left-hand limit ?

Comment: So the left-hand limit is $1$ ?

Comment: Yes, in fact $f(x)\equiv 1$ on the interval $(-1,0)$. (It's also $1$ on the interval $(-2,-1)$ but for a different reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following graph:

You will get the answer automatically.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8p190y7wr2

Hint: The limit as a whole is not defined, because negative limit is not equal to positive limit.

Comment: Thanks but sometimes graphing programs can lead us to the wrong answer . For example here if you consider $a_n = 1/n$ and $1/{(n+0.5)}$ then you will notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = 0$ . Therefore the right-hand limit doesn't exist but you can't see that from the graph .

Comment: The Desmos graph plots all values correctly (at least in the vicinity of $x=0$) _except_ when $x$ is the reciprocal of a positive integer. But it's those values that cause the limit as $x\to0+$ to be undefined.

Comment: Graphs are useful only for simple functions and for the current example it does not plot the points for $x=1/n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.