# Plotting $f(x) = x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$

Tags: limits, graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to plot $f(x) = x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ near the point zero for finding its limit but I can't choose proper intervals and plot it .

Comment: From GeoGebra, it looks like the limit at zero is 1 but the zoom seems kind of 'infinite'.

Answer (score 3):

On an unrelated note, it's easier to calculate the limit than you think. Since $k - 1\le\lfloor k \rfloor \le k $, we know that $$\lim_{x \to 0}x\left(\frac{1}x - 1\right)\le \lim_{x \to 0}x\left\lfloor {1 \over x}\right\rfloor \le \lim_{x \to 0}x \left( \frac{1}x\right)$$Now you see the squeeze theorem in action. It's not exactly a good idea to make an exact plot of this function by hand, since you've got all integers covered up as you approach zero, but you may tentatively understand that for large numbers, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ may be treated as $x$, the latter being continuous instead of discrete.

Comment: I added a presumably missing $\left\lfloor {1 \over x} \right\rfloor$. Please, check that this is indeed what was intended.

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thanks but I want to solve $\lim_{x \to 0^{-} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor$ . It's impossible to do that without knowing graph around zero .

Comment: @S.H.W No, it *is* possible, since Parth Kohli has shown that both limits are zero.

Comment: @lisyarus Take a look at this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575602/a-complicated-limit-involving-floor-function

Comment: @S.H.W (I meant that the limits are $1$, of course).

I don't see how the link you provided justifies that evaluating the limit is impossible without plotting. Are you saying that the proof by Parth Kohli is incorrect?

Comment: @lisyarus The limit of $x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor $ as  $x \to 0$ is $1$ but $\lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor $  as $x \to 0$ doesn't exist .

Answer (score 2):

I switched to $1/x$ for large positive $x,$ picture gives better idea this way. I would have preferred using a different letter, say $t = 1/x,$ but I do not yet know how to do that. So, think of the graphs as indicating that the limit as $t \rightarrow +\infty \; \; \; \lfloor t \rfloor /t = 1,$ and 
$t \rightarrow -\infty \; \; \; \lfloor t \rfloor /t = 1.$ That can then be applied to $x = 1/t$ at $0^+$ and $0^-$

Apparently the intended question is to apply the floor function **again.** In the graphs below, one can see easily what happens in the positive case and the negative case, when $t$ is an integer and when $t$ is not an integer. Just look at the  graphs, think of what the floor function does if applied that one more time. Note: I did try writing an extra floor function in the graph, the computer did not do it correctly.

[image]

Next for negative $x$ 
[image]

Comment: Very nice but how we can apply this idea to solve $\lim_{x \to 0^{-} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W using my letter $t = 1/x,$ four things, as $t$ moves away from the origin: what happens to  $\lfloor \lfloor t \rfloor / t \rfloor$ when $t>1$  and (A) $t$ is an integer (B) $t$ is not an integer? What happens to  $\lfloor \lfloor t \rfloor / t \rfloor$ when $t<-1$  and (C) $t$ is an integer (D) $t$ is not an integer?

Comment: Okay , it seems when $t \to \infty$ then $\lfloor \lfloor t \rfloor / t \rfloor \to 0$ but it's not true . In fact the limit doesn't exist .

Comment: @S.H.W you wanted separate consideration for positive and negative. Answering my questions A,B,C,D. gives what you want. Meanwhile, I did put an extra floor function in desmos, it did not do it correctly. I think the message is that we cannot expect a computer graph to deal with isolated points (in this case, integers) where the graph is different.

Comment: (A) the value of $\lfloor \lfloor t \rfloor / t \rfloor$ is $1$ . (B)  the value of $\lfloor \lfloor t \rfloor / t \rfloor$ is $0$ . So it seems that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor = 0$ (like $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = -1 ) $ but it's not true . If we consider $a_n = 1/n $ and $b_n = 1/(n + 0.5)$ then the sequences $f(a_n) $ and $f(b_n)$ converge to $1$ and $0$ respectively . Therefore the limit doesn't exist . It sounds like a contradiction .

Comment: @S.H.W that's what happens for (A),(B), $t > 0.$ Good.  Different when $t < 0,$ indeed best to consider $t < -1$

Answer (score 1):

This is what I obtain from GeoGebra:

[image]

No matter how much I zoomed in, I eventually ended up with a similar looking pattern so I suppose there is no 'appropriate' interval to plot this function.

Using Wolfram|Alpha, I get the series representation
$$x\left\lfloor{\frac 1x}\right\rfloor=1 - \frac x2 + \frac x\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 k \pi}{x}\right)}{k}$$
which confirms the suspicion that
$$\lim_{x\to0}x\left\lfloor{\frac 1x}\right\rfloor=1$$
 <s>but I have no idea how the series is derived.</s>

Did some [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Continuity_and_series_expansions) just now and it looks like the series can be quite easily obtained.

Comment: The question is more about plotting than the actual limit, but if you wanted to derive the limit it is very easy from $x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor = 1 - x(1/x - \lfloor 1/x \rfloor)$, after observing that the quantity in parentheses always lies in the interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: I got a similar graph in Maple. Maple also evaluates the limit to be 1.

Comment: For every $x>0$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}<x<\frac{1}{n}$. In that case, $\lfloor1/x\rfloor=n$ and $\frac{n}{n+1}<x\lfloor1/x\rfloor=xn<1$. As $x$ approaches $0$, $n$ approaches $\infty$ and $x\lfloor1/x\rfloor$ is sandwiched and tends to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

When $\frac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ we have $n \leq \frac{1}{x} < n+1$ and thus $\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = n$ and $x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = nx.$ The range on the interval $\frac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ will then be $(\frac{n}{n+1}, \frac{n}{n}] = (1-\frac{1}{n+1}, 1].$ From this it's obvious that the limit is $1.$

Comment: Thanks but how we can solve $\lim_{x \to 0^{+} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor $  and $\lim_{x \to 0^{-} } \lfloor x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor \rfloor $ then ?

Comment: Since the range of $x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor$ is $(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}, 1]$ we have $\lfloor x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \rfloor = 0$ if $\frac{1}{n+1} < x < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\lfloor x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \rfloor = 1$ if $x = \frac{1}{n}.$ Therefore, those limits don't exist.

Comment: md2, not quite, see my answer using $t = 1/x$

Comment: I saw when I plotted the graph in GeoGebra that when $-2 < x < 0$ we have $\lfloor x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \rfloor = 1.$  My error above is that when $n<-1,$ i.e. $-1<x<0,$ the interval $(1-\frac{1}{n+1}, 1]$ "reverses" to $[1, 1-\frac{1}{n+1})$ since $1-\frac{1}{n+1} > 1.$ and so $\lfloor x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \rfloor = 1.$ Thus the limit from the negative side exists and equals $1$.

Comment: For completeness, when $x \leq -1$ we have $-1 \leq \frac{1}{x} < 0$ so $\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = -1$ and $x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = -x = |x|$. Thus $\lfloor x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \rfloor = \lfloor |x| \rfloor = |x|.$

Answer (score 1):

Check the graph at [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20floor(1%2Fx)*x%20%20x%3D-0.0001..0.0001)

The the limit is 1 as you can see in the graph.

If you want to explain this in a more rigorous way, let's apply limit definition.

Given any $\epsilon >0$ you can find an $x_0$ such as $|f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $x < x_0$. Let's just work with the limit from the right, for simplicity:

$$ |x_0 [\frac{1}{x_0}] - 1 |< \epsilon$$

We also know that $[x] = x - \{x\}$, where $\{\}$ means the fractional part. So we can rewrite the former expression as:

$$|x_0 (\frac{1}{x_0} - \{\frac{1}{x_0}\}) -1| < \epsilon$$

Since we are operating from the right, we just need to swap the sign to get rid of absolute value:

$$ 1-  x_0 (\frac{1}{x_0} - \{\frac{1}{x_0}\})  < \epsilon$$

$$  x_0\{\frac{1}{x_0}\} < \epsilon$$

The worst case scenario is when fractional part of $x_0$ is as close as posible to $1$, taking $x_0 < \epsilon$  assures the limit definition is always followed.

So we can conclude

$$\lim_{x-> 0^{+}}{x[\frac{1}{x}]} = 1$$

Similar you can proceed to calculate the limit from the left, just take care with the absolute value function.